# block few url with .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, block

i am trying to block few urls using .htaccess

i am trying this code in my .htaccess but its not working

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*(wp-content)|(phpMyAdmin)|(mp4:).* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
```

when i go to www.theawesomecoder.com/mp4.php its getting rendered rather then showing forbidden

i am  trying to block checking words in url which should be case sensitive

if some one types mp4 or MP4 they should get forbidden

Pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because your regex is incorrect `mp4:` instead of `mp4`.

Simplify your regex and make sure this **very first** rule in your `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (wp-content|phpMyAdmin|mp4) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```